# jQuery: Bind 2 events and execute only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, jquery-focusout

I have a table where, when I click on a cell, the cell turns editable.
If I change the content of the cell, I want to execute an AJAX request to save the data to the database, only if:

1. Focus out of the cell
2. Press enter key

The problem is that the event is executed twice if I press "Enter" and once if I focusout of the cell; and I think I know why: enter keypress qualifies as focusout as well. This is the code:

```
$(document).on('focusout keypress', '.row_data', function(event){..}
```

I tried to limit that inside the event:

```
if ( (event.type === "keypress" && event.which === 13) || (event.type === "focusout" && event.which !== 13) ) {...}
```

but unfortunately, it will not work.

Any idea why this is failing? Any idea how i can make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a flag to see if this event has already fired before firing again?

```
$(document).on('focusout keypress', '.row_data', function(event){
    if ($(this).data('has-event-fired') {
        // Event already fired! Reset our flag and bail!
        $(this).data('has-event-fired', false);
        return;
    }

    // First time we're firing here. Set our flag and fire event as normal.
    $(this).data('has-event-fired', true);

    // Rest of event handler
}
```

That should force your event to only fire once per action, and will reset itself after both events fire. It could get wonky if only one event manages to fire, though, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This actually works, provided that I set 'has-event-fired' to false during focus event.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `event.stopPropagation();` to your callback function and then only listen to focusout

```
$('td').on('focusout', '.row_data', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: If i only use focusout event then it works. I know because this is how i started the implementation. But i need this to work when pressing Enter key as well.

Comment: also it's better to add the listener on the table cells not the whole document. That is probably why it is not working for pressing enter, attach it to TD

Comment: By pressing Enter the cell is expanding to a new line if you don't restrict it with keypress and 13. Also, by adding the event listener on the cell still causes the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() can stop controlling this default behavior and you can check condition accordingly.

Comment: I use event.preventDefault() but it does not solve this issue.